# Convert a string with ns precision to datetime in a panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having a hard time converting a string with ns precision in a datetime format in a panda dataframe.

I have a data frame like the following :

```
print df
     Event     Time
0    A         08:00:00.123456789
1    B         08:00:00.234567890
2    C         08:00:00.345678901
```

I would like to convert the Time column from string to datetime without losing the ns precision.
I tried following :

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
```

but when I print the `df` I see that I only have up to `us` precision.

`df['Time'] = df['Time'].astype('datetime64[ns]')`

but here I get an error like

> "Error parsing datetime string "08:00:00.345678901" at position 2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following did the trick for me:

```
>>> df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S.%f')
>>> df
  Event                          Time
0     A 1900-01-01 08:00:00.123456789
1     B 1900-01-01 08:00:00.234567890
2     C 1900-01-01 08:00:00.345678901
```

As noted in the [documentation for `pd.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) concerning the `format` argument:

> strftime to parse time, eg “%d/%m/%Y”, **note that “%f” will parse all the way up to nanoseconds**.

Comment: Works great ! Thanks a lot !